# mPDF: Script does not work for codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I am trying to create pdf files using mPDF and CodeIgneter.
In the controllor I have following script:

```
$pdfFilePath = FCPATH."/pdf/report/test.pdf";
$data['page_title'] = 'Hello world'; // pass data to the view

if (file_exists($pdfFilePath) == FALSE) {

ini_set('memory_limit','32M');
$html = $this->load->view('pdf_output', $data, true); // render the view into HTML

$this->load->library('m_pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822)); 
$pdf->WriteHTML($html); // write the HTML into the PDF
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F'); 
}
```

I am getting this eror message and I cannot understand the reason.

**Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$pdf**

Comment: it should be $m_pdf if the class name is m_pdf change it from $pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In fact I had forgotten to declare the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put mpdf60 folder in Library.

In controller put following code.

```
public function doprint($book_id,$pdf=false)
{
    $this->load->library('parser'); 
    $page_data['sold_book'] = "Hello world data";    
    $output = $this->parser->parse('sold_book_detail_print',$page_data,true);   
    if ($pdf=='print')
       $this->_gen_pdf($output); 
    else
        $this->output->set_output($output);             
}
//GENRATE PDF FILE
public function _gen_pdf($html,$paper='A4')
{
    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "output_pdf_name.pdf";
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('mpdf60/mpdf');
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8',$paper);

    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Put following code in view.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/soldtextbook/doprint/<?php echo $row->buy_book_id; ?>/print" target="_blank" class="post-ad">print shipping Detail</a>
```

And create file.php in view.and write html in file.php
Ex:

```
<?php echo $sold_book; ?>
```